# AchartEngine add text with superscript

Tags: android, achartengine

Is it possible to add superscript, or subscript characters to AchartEngine's x axes label, like you did in Microsoft Word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
    str = str.replaceAll("0", "⁰");
    str = str.replaceAll("1", "¹");
    str = str.replaceAll("2", "²");
    str = str.replaceAll("3", "³");
    str = str.replaceAll("4", "⁴");
    str = str.replaceAll("5", "⁵");
    str = str.replaceAll("6", "⁶");
    str = str.replaceAll("7", "⁷");
    str = str.replaceAll("8", "⁸");
    str = str.replaceAll("9", "⁹");  

    String  str = "X2";
    String xtitle = str.replaceAll("2", "²");      
    renderer.setXTitle( xtitle);
```

Otherwise you can do

```
 CharSequence xtitle  =   Html.fromHtml("X<sup>2</sup>");
```

But then you have to change achartengine library and change String to CharSequence because CharSequence cannot be cast to string.

Comment: I tried this on Android TextView but it works for superscript 1 to 4 only. It does not work with 0, 5 to 9 while printing on the TextView!!!