# Set Y Axis Minimum Value to be a negative value does not work

Tags: android, achartengine

I am building an Android Application and I am using AChartEngine to display a graph and values I obtain.

However, there are times that the values I obtain contain negative values and the linechart would dip but I would not see my the point. I already tried doing:

```
mRenderer.setYAxisMin(-20);
```

where mRenderer is a `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer`, however, my graphs minimum y value is still 0 and the user would have to pan to see the negative value.

Is there a way to set the graph in such a way that the minimum value is negative?

Here is my entire code for rendering the graph:

```
    renderer3 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer3.setLineWidth(2);
    renderer3.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    renderer3.setDisplayBoundingPoints(true);
    renderer3.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    renderer3.setPointStrokeWidth(3);
    renderer3.setAnnotationsTextSize(20);

    renderer3.setAnnotationsColor(Color.BLACK);
    renderer3.setAnnotationsTextAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
    renderer3.setAnnotationsTextSize(25);

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataSet = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataSet.addSeries(accelerationSeries);

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer3);

    mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00)); // transparent margins
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);
    mRenderer.setYAxisMax(10);
    mRenderer.setYAxisMin(-10);
    mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    mRenderer.setShowGrid(true); // we show the grid

    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(40);
    mRenderer.setShowAxes(true);
    mRenderer.setShowCustomTextGrid(true);
    mRenderer.setShowCustomTextGridY(true);

    mRenderer.setYTitle("Acceleration (Meters/Second Squared)");
    mRenderer.setXTitle("Time (Seconds)");
    mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0, 255, 255, 255));
    mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(20);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(25);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
    mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(25);
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{ 100, 100, 100, 100 });

    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(40);
    mRenderer.setGridColor(Color.GRAY);

    GraphicalView chartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getBaseContext(), dataSet, mRenderer);
```

Comment: For sure. Have a look at the demo examples. http://www.achartengine.org/content/demo.html

Comment: @DerGolem thank you for the link. I imported the code into Android studio and checked the `getDemoRenderer()` function, however, I don't see anything glaring with my code. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
mRenderer.setYAxisMin(-10);
mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
```

The second call overrides the first one.

Therefore, you first set the minimum to **-10**.
Soon after, you re-set it to **0**.

The solution is to remove

```
mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
```

Comment: It happens. Yo add something and forget to comment out the previous code. This is why I add the new code AFTER the old one (which is also logical: BEFORE, it was that, NOW it is this). ;)

Comment: One last, how do you superscript annotations?)

Comment: I already tried: `accelerationSeries.addAnnotation("(" + entry + " m/s" + Html.fromHtml("<sup>2</sup>)"), accelerationSeries.getX(i), accelerationSeries.getY(i));` but that did not superscript my value.

Comment: Here is an alternate solution. Maybe it fixes your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20443354/2649012

Comment: Don't worry. I'm glad, if I can help.